# gRPC request with IntelliJ http client

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to make a simple gRPC request **in IntelliJ** to a service that looks like this

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service UserContactDetailsService {
    rpc getContactDetails (google.protobuf.UInt64Value) returns (UserContactDetailsMessage);
}

message UserContactDetailsMessage {
  uint64 userId = 1;
  string salutation = 2;
  string firstname = 3;
  string lastname = 4;
}
```

The message for the request type is defined as

```
message UInt64Value {
  // The uint64 value.
  uint64 value = 1;
}
```

I've already tried the following

```
GRPC localhost:31995/user.UserContactDetailsService/getContactDetails

{
  "value": 1
}
```

which returns this error

> com.intellij.grpc.requests.RejectedRPCException: Unable to build message from provided request body`

Is it possible to make a request with IntelliJ like this?
If so, how does it need to look like?

**Update**: When I duplicate the imported google message and create my own like so

```
message Number {
  uint64 value = 1;
}
```

The request works fine

Also found a related YouTrack issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283452